# How to get the UP nodes excluding DOWN nodes through programming in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I'm using Apache Cassandra through thrift in C++. And I want to get all the nodes in the cluster whose status is **UP**, **excluding** those nodes with status **DOWN**, **through thrift programming**. The two interfaces `describe_ring()` and `describe_token_map()` provided in cassandra.thrift will give me all the nodes in the cluster, both **UP** and **DOWN**. But I only want to get the **UP** nodes and choose one to connect to. Could anyone find a way for me to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about C++, but in Java, class MetaData has a getAllHosts() method that returns a set of 'Host's, and the Host class has an "isUp" method. I would call this method on each returned Host to filter for the desired ones. Don't know if this helps you with your requirement in C++.

Comment: @Pradyumn: You are referring to the Datastax drivers. That's not exactly the same. The Thrift API does not have that `isUp()` method/field. But good hint anyway, and [here is the relevant code](https://github.com/tfredrich/cassandra-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Host.java) for that class.

Comment: @JensG: I have to send a test message to every node and determine whether the node is up based on the response, in C++. Is that right?

Comment: At least that's what I would do. Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Granted it's still in beta, but is there a reason you DON'T switch to the DataStax C++ CQL-based driver? https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver Thrift is due to be retired in C* 3.0.

Comment: @mildewey: Yes, because it's in beta and maybe not stable...I keep wondering that how is CQL implemented to replace thrift? In my view, CQL is just like SQL. Does CQL also re-implement the underlying RPC mechanism? In my own code, actually I use the CQL query in the thrift API call, e.g: `thrift_client.execute_cql3_query("SELECT * FROM table;");` What's more, can CQL solve my question above? Thanks.

Comment: The _driver_ based on CQL will solve your problem as Pradyumn pointed out. In general, however, properly used CQL is faster in execution and easier to develop. As to the beta status of C++, it's under very active development, and if the track record of the DataStax drivers development team is anything to go by, the GA is just around the corner. Which is to say, starting to use it now should carry minimal risk and will certainly save you headaches in the long run.